# Github password Changed

Tags: git, github

I have a repository set up on github and everything worked well, however, my github account password changed to one with the `@` symbol in it.  Trying to change the password using

```
git clone https://user:newPassword@github.....
```

Because of the `@` symbol, it thinks part of the password is part of the HTTPS url

Any way around this?  Pretty new to github

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways around this, but you shouldn’t be putting your password in the Git URL. Generate an SSH key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Add it to your GitHub account in [your account settings](https://github.com/settings/ssh), then use it:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@github.com/…
```

GitHub offers a few resources on the subject too:

- [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)
- [Common SSH Problems](https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles)

Comment: +1 should be doing this anyways for security. otherwise your password will be visible in your terminal history (among other reasons).